# Finding the distribution of the number of tosses it takes to observe all 6 sides of a fair die

Tags: probability, dice, coupon-collector

I found this question on [http://www.cis.jhu.edu/~xye/papers_and_ppts/ppts/SolutionsToFourProblemsOfRollingADie.pdf](http://www.cis.jhu.edu/%7Exye/papers_and_ppts/ppts/SolutionsToFourProblemsOfRollingADie.pdf). It is Q(d):

> Roll x times until getting all the faces from “1” to “6”, what’s the distribution of x?

The analytical derivation starts on pg 3 of 5 towards the middle of the page.

They show that

$$
P(\text{First x-1  rolls have all faces but 6}) = P_{x-1}\left(\cap_{i=1}^5 A_i \cap A_6^c  \right)
$$
where $A_i$ is the event that we toss the $i$-th number.

Why is this probability not $\left(\frac{5}{6} \right)^{x-1}$? Each of the first $x-1$ rolls are independent, and there is each a probability of $\frac{5}{6}$ of not tossing a $6$.

Comment: $\left(\frac 56\right)^{x-1}$ would be the probability that you get a non-six $x-1$ times. Thus, getting a one $x-1$ times in a row would be a success.

Comment: @lulu I agree. I misread/misunderstood what they meant by "First x-1 rolls have all faces but 6." I thought it said "First x-1 rolls can be anything but a 6." But the "all" part means we need to have visited 1,2,3,4,5 in those x-1 rolls.

Answer (score 1):

You are computing the probability that there are no $6$s in the first $x-1$ rolls, but they want to compute the probability that faces $1,2,3,4,5$ each appear at least once in the first $x-1$ rolls.